# How are transactions signed when using web3js with Infura?

Tags: web3js, transactions, infura, signature

So far so good, all the examples I have seen online using infura are only code examples where the blockchain is queried. I have not seen one where transactions is actually sent to the blockchain.

Since transactions require signing, I was wondering how will the code look like if I want to submit a transaction to the Ethereum blockchain using Infura?

Comment: It depends on the use case you can use [@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) to sign programmatically or require users a wallet like metamask.